# Problem with ajax and RadTreeView

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

Hi all :
I have a user control which contain RadTreeView from Telerik inside ModalPopupExtender , the previous  control loaded at runtime  :

```
DashBoardDesignerCell tempCell = LoadControl("~/UserControls/DashBoardDesignerControls/DashboardDesignerCell.ascx") as DashBoardDesignerCell;
```

When SelectedNodeChanged occurs the ModalPopupExtender disappears.

This is the full code for user contrl:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DashBoardDesignerCell.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="RightBI.UserControls.DashBoardDesignerControls.DashBoardDesignerCell" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/PresentationControls/SelectPresentationControl.ascx" TagPrefix="rightbicontrols" TagName="selectpresentationcontrol" %>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="dashboardDesignerCellUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style='width: 100%; border-style: solid; border-width: thin;
            border-color: Silver;'>
            <thead>
                <tr style='background: blue'>
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton SkinID="selectControlButton" runat="server" ID="addControlButton"
                            OnClick="okButton_Click" />
                        <asp:ImageButton SkinID="deleteControlButton" runat="server" ID="removeControlButton"
                            OnClick="removeControlButton_Click" />
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" Style='display: none;'>
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                        <ajax:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="addControlButton" ID="selectPresentationControlModalPopupExtender"
                            PopupControlID="popupSelectPresentationControl" CancelControlID="cancelButton"
                            BackgroundCssClass="popup_black_BG">
                        </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="popupSelectPresentationControl" Style='display: none;'>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="popupSelectUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <div class="popup_container">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="popup_table">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="popup_header_left">
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="popup_header_middle">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="popup_header_right">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="popup_main_left">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="popup_main">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                    <div class="popup_content">
                                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style='width: 100%'>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <span>Caption (*):</span>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="captionTextBox">
                                                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="captionTextBox"
                                                                        ValidationGroup="SelectPresentationControl" ErrorMessage="Caption is required."
                                                                        Text="*">
                                                                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                                    <rightbicontrols:selectpresentationcontrol id="selectControl" runat="server" />
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                                    <telerik:RadButton ID="okButton" Text="Save" SkinID="okButton" runat="server" CommandName="Save"
                                                                        ValidationGroup="SelectPresentationControl" OnClick="okButton_Click">
                                                                    </telerik:RadButton>
                                                                    <telerik:RadButton ID="cancelButton" Text="Cancel" SkinID="cancelButton" runat="server"
                                                                        CommandName="Cancel">
                                                                    </telerik:RadButton>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="popup_main_right">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="popup_footer_left">
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="popup_footer_middle">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="popup_footer_right">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style='min-height: 150px;'>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="controlUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="controlPanel">
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

public Guid DashboardColumnID
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["DashboardColumnID"] == null)
                {
                    return Guid.Empty;
                }
                return new Guid(ViewState["DashboardColumnID"].ToString());
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["DashboardColumnID"] = value;
            }
        }

        protected Guid DashboardZoneID
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["DashboardZoneID"] == null)
                {
                    return Guid.Empty;
                }
                return new Guid(ViewState["DashboardZoneID"].ToString());
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["DashboardZoneID"] = value;
            }
        }

        protected Guid PresentationControlID
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["PresentationControlID"] == null)
                {
                    return Guid.Empty;
                }
                return new Guid(ViewState["PresentationControlID"].ToString());
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["PresentationControlID"] = value;
            }
        }

        protected void LoadDashboardZone()
        {
            DashboardColumn dashboardColumn = DashboardColumn.GetDashboardColumn(DashboardColumnID);
            if (dashboardColumn.DashboardZones.Count == 1)
            {
                DashboardZoneID = dashboardColumn.DashboardZones.FirstOrDefault().Id;
            }
            if (DashboardZoneID == Guid.Empty)
            {
                removeControlButton.Visible = false;
                addControlButton.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                removeControlButton.Visible = true;
                addControlButton.Visible = false;
            }
            controlPanel.Controls.Clear();
            if (DashboardZoneID != Guid.Empty)
            {
                DashboardDesignerZone zone = LoadControl("~/UserControls/DashBoardDesignerControls/DashboardZone.ascx") as DashboardDesignerZone;
                zone.DashboardZoneID = DashboardZoneID;
                controlPanel.Controls.Add(zone);
            }
            controlUpdatePanel.Update();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //
            String code = "function openWindow() {var oWnd = $find('" + selectPresentationWindow .ClientID+ "');oWnd.show();  }";
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "OpenRadWindow", code , true);
            LoadDashboardZone();
        }

        protected void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddPresentationControl(captionTextBox.Text, selectControl.PresentationControlId);
            //dashboardDesignerCellUpdatePanel.Update();
        }

        protected void removeControlButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DashboardZone.RemoveDashboardZone(this.DashboardZoneID))
            {
                PresentationControlID = Guid.Empty;
                DashboardZoneID = Guid.Empty;
                LoadDashboardZone();
                //dashboardDesignerCellUpdatePanel.Update();
            }
        }

        public void AddPresentationControl(String caption, Guid presentationControlID)
        {
            DashboardZone tempDashboardZone = DashboardZone.AddDashboardZone(caption, DashboardColumnID, presentationControlID);
            if (tempDashboardZone != null)
            {
                PresentationControlID = presentationControlID;
                DashboardZoneID = tempDashboardZone.Id;
                LoadDashboardZone();
            }
        }
```

Is There any idea???

Answer (score 0):

Do you by any means do postback or ajax request when a treeview node is selected? This might be potential cause the modal popup extender is closed. Why you do not use the Telerik Ajax window instead, to compare the results? Also I assume that you load the user control dynamically on init or load of the page and clear the Controls collection of the container before adding the user control inside it.

Comment: i replaced ModalPopupExtender with RadWindow but the same error occurs ??

Comment: From your previous explanation I had the impression that the popup just disappeared without errors being generated, or am I wrong? You can post the entire code (inside the user control and the complete runtime loading logic), it can help to provide more definite answer than simply guessing.